# C++ Copy an object through constructor

Tags: c++, class, copy

I am having a few problems with creating a new class by copying other objects to it. From what i can see, the code below works, however my compiler states it's missing a default constructor of the class material. From what i can see, this is not needed. Am i doing something wrong here?

First class constructor:

```
    shadingBatch::shadingBatch(const vertexAttribLayout& layout, const material& batchMaterial){
    dataFormat_ = layout;
    batchMaterial_ = *(new material(batchMaterial));
}
```

I have also tried

```
shadingBatch::shadingBatch(const vertexAttribLayout& layout, const material& batchMaterial){
            dataFormat_ = layout;
            batchMaterial_ = batchMaterial;
        }
```

But the same compiler error is returned.

Second class definition

```
    class material {
protected:
    shader shader_;
public:
    material (const shader* shaderProgram);
    material (const material&);
    ~material();

    void compileShader();
} ;
```

Second class copy constructor

```
material::material(const material& other){
        shader_ = *(new shader(other.shader_));
    }
```

Edit: As requested,

First class definition

```
class shadingBatch {
    friend class cheeseRenderer;
protected:
    std::vector<primitive*> primitives_;
    std::vector<vertex> vertices_;
    std::vector<GLuint> elements_;
    vertexAttribLayout dataFormat_;
    material batchMaterial_;
    GLuint VAO_;
    GLuint VBO_;
    GLuint EBO_;
public:
    ~shadingBatch();
    GLuint updateBatch (void);
    void addPrimitive (primitive*);
    shadingBatch(const vertexAttribLayout&, const material&);
private:
    void updatePrimitives (void);
    void setVertexAttributes(void);
} ;
```

And where the constructor is called:

```
shader* defaultShader = new shader(fragmentSource,vertexSource);
material* defaultMaterial = new material(defaultShader);
vertexAttribLayout* defaultVertexData = new vertexAttribLayout();
shadingBatch* batch = new shadingBatch(*defaultVertexData,*defaultMaterial);
cheeseRenderer renderer(*batch);
```

Comment: please add error message. When you miss a default constructor, 99.999999% of the time your compiler is true. It's common that one class has your missing default constructor class as a member and you don't initialise that member in your class correctly.

Comment: Can you show us `shadingBatch` definition and the call for its constructor?

Comment: Don't use `new` unless you really need it and you know what you are doing. Currently, it is only causing trouble and resource leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not the construction of the objects, but copying the arguments into the internal objects *after* they have been constructed. You want to look up the concept of initialization lists. The constructor you want to implement looks like this:

```
shadingBatch::shadingBatch(const vertexAttribLayout& layout, const material& batchMaterial)
  : dataFormat_(layout), batchMaterial_(batchMaterial) // <-- initialization list
{}
```

If you do not initialize you class members explicitly in the initialization list, they will be default constructed. Or at least, the compiler will try. Material seems not to have a default constructor, so the compiler complains in both your attempts.

Sidenote: the first constructor attempt has another error, a memory leak, since you create an object via `new` and neither store nor delete the resulting pointer, its memory (and the object itself) will be lost forever.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should use initializer list. Any member variable object not initialized explicitly in initializer list will have it's default constructor called before constructor body is executed. Then you also do new, but never delete it (because you lose the pointer), so your constructor leaks memory. Try this:

```
shadingBatch::shadingBatch(const vertexAttribLayout& layout, 
                           const material& batchMaterial) :
    dataFormat_(layout)
   ,batchMaterial_(batchMaterial)
{
}
```

Above assumes that both `dataFormat_` and `batchMaterial_` are member variables of class `shadingBatch`, and they are declared in that order in the class definition, so fix as needed if this is not so.

---

Your `material::material` also has both the memory leak and default constructor problems, so you need something like:

```
material::material(const material& other) : shader_(other.shader_) {}
```

(And possibly more initialization code if there's more to do, but you get the idea.)